The accuracy in the neural network does not change
The code of a fully connected NN (I know what is better convolutional, I will do it further), which determines the numbers from the MNIST dataset. When enabled, accuracy does not change at all. What could be the mistake? I have divided the code cells with lines, and marked with comments what is where. I apologize in advance for a lot of code and long answers.
import os
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision import transforms as tfs


data_tfs = tfs.Compose([
    tfs.ToTensor(),
    tfs.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))
])

# install for train and test
root = './'
train_dataset = MNIST(root, train=True,  transform=data_tfs, download=True)
val_dataset  = MNIST(root, train=False, transform=data_tfs, download=True)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True) 

valid_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------
#Creating the model
activation = nn.ELU

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    #YOUR CODE. Add layers to your sequential class
    nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=128),
    nn.ELU(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10),
    nn.ELU()
)
---------------------------------------------------------------
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()#YOUR CODE. Select a loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

loaders = {"train": train_dataloader, "valid": valid_dataloader}
---------------------------------------------------------------
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
---------------------------------------------------------------
max_epochs = 10
accuracy = {"train": [], "valid": []}

class Identical(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x

activation = nn.ELU

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    #YOUR CODE. Add layers to your sequential class
    nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=128),
    nn.ELU(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10),
    nn.ELU()
)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()#YOUR CODE. Select a loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

loaders = {"train": train_dataloader, "valid": valid_dataloader}

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    for k, dataloader in loaders.items():
        epoch_correct = 0
        epoch_all = 0
        for x_batch, y_batch in dataloader:
            if k == "train":
              model.train()
              optimizer.zero_grad()
              outp = model(x_batch)
              outp = outp[:y_batch.shape[0]] #otherwise, the last batch is less than necessary
            else:
              model.eval()
              with torch.no_grad():
                outp = model(x_batch)
                outp = outp[:y_batch.shape[0]]
            preds = outp.argmax(-1)
            correct =  (preds == y_batch).sum()
            all =  tuple(preds.shape)[0]
            epoch_correct += correct.item()
            epoch_all += all
            if k == "train":
                loss = criterion(outp, y_batch)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
        if k == "train":
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}")
        print(f"Loader: {k}. Accuracy: {epoch_correct/epoch_all}")
        accuracy[k].append(epoch_correct/epoch_all)


We cannot run this code, a lot of details are missing, you should include an MRE.

could you add data loading and preprocessing steps?

you should provide your model and which dataset your using

sorry for the long answer. I've attached everything you asked for. thanks

I have changed your model to the code below, because you are flattening the images and in the next layers input the dimension should be 28*28=784:
model = nn.Sequential(
nn.Flatten(),
#YOUR CODE. Add layers to your sequential class
nn.Linear(in_features=784, out_features=128),
nn.ELU(),
nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10),
nn.ELU()
)

after this change the model runs perfectly with this results:

train. Accuracy: 0.98535
valid. Accuracy: 0.9759

